# What´s the diference between a UDF and a saved Query in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

How can I "script" inside a SQLite database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is just a library, its code is running inside your application. You just pass your application's functions to SQLite then they will be accessible inside the SQL statements. For example in PHP you will use [`sqlite_create_function()`](http://php.net/sqlite-create-function).

Comment: I am sorry. I mean SQLite Manager not SQLite. I know that's just a way to work it, but by now is the one that I've found.

Comment: The functions used by SQLite pertain to the application which uses the SQLite library. There is no way to tear off part of the application's code, store it in SQLite and run it later.